# Create Analysis Services project in 2012, deploy to 2005-2012. Compatibility?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

I would like to create Analysis Services project (data cube) in Visual Studio 2010 which is in SQL Server 2012 but need to be able to deploy my cubes to older SQL servers. (2005 and newer)

Is this supported scenario? I found on MS sites that there is possibility to set CompatibilityLevel. But I'm not sure..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this personally, but in analysis aervices project properties on build tab you've got `Deployment Server Version` where you can choose versions 11.0, 10.0 and 9.0. So it seems that versions of SQL Server downto 9.0 (2005) are supported.
[image]